# Is this LSTM model underfitting, overfitting or something else?

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am doing a sequence prediction of stock using Keras LSTM model. The model fit history shows a different graph that I seldom see before.
[image]

Below is my code:

keras_callbacks = [
EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', mode='max', verbose=1, patience=50),
ModelCheckpoint(filepath=model_path, monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True, verbose=1, mode='min',
initial_value_threshold=0.1)
]

```
batch_size = 10
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(X.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(96))
model.add(Dense(y.shape[1], activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X, y, epochs=300, validation_split=0.33, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2,
                    callbacks=keras_callbacks)

# plot the training history
plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='Validation Loss')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Mean Squared Error')
plt.savefig('c:/tmp/stock/nyse1/' + basename + '.png')
plt.show()
```

The model input is a list of lists with varied length, while the output is just the direction of a stock, 1 meaning long and 0 meaning short.

May someone interpret what the picture means and advice me how to improve?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jonathan,

I had similar problem with Adam and LSTM. I reduced the oscillations by [increasing the value of epsilon and reducing the value of the learning rate for Adam](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Adam). I would also suggest to reduce your batch size but it is already quite low. [This question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/26803/porpoising-in-latter-stages-of-validation-loss-and-mse-charts-in-keras) has an interesing answer that is relevant.

Charles